# Generate ID based on text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a simple table on it. 
The purpose of it is to log the price of a cryptocurrency I'm watching.

[image: TABLE]

When I'm entering new data, I make a new line, put in the time and date, write which currency it is and whether it's down or up from my last listing.

I'm wanting to put an ID column in to organise each cryptocurrency in how they're listed in the top 100 currencies.

In this list you have `ARK`, `EOS`, `FunFair`, `IOTA`, and `NEM`. 
The order is `IOTA`, `NEM`, `EOS`, `ARK`, `FunFair` in the list. So if I sort by Item/CC it should go by time/date, then ID, then name putting `IOTA` at the top with a simple `1` in the column.

The question is, how do I write something like:

```
=if C:C = "IOTA" B:B = "1"
```

Comment: I just figured I can put 1. IOTA 2. NEM in the Item/CC column, but I figure this could be handy to know for future.

Comment: What do you expect the table to look like if its working? sorry not sure i understand your question (as in can you manually populate the ID column too please)

Comment: I'd like the ID to be 1,2,3,4,5, or 6. So if C column = iota, B column = 1.

Comment: I could put 1. IOTA in column C and write `=(LOWER((LEFT(C11,1))))` which wold take the first character (1) from column C. But that defeats the purpose. I want it to see IOTA in column C and write a 1 in column B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B2 and copied down should suit:

```
=MATCH(LEFT(C2),{"I","N","E","A","F"},0)
```

Alternatively set up a Custom List (how is off topic here) and sort ColumnC on that.

Comment: Hello, I've since dropped this project, but your answer appears to answer the question. Thank you!